# How to ignore warnings - finding the actual warning / error

Tags: android-studio, dart

How can I ignore a Warning / Error in Android Studio?

Like the following, I can see the warning saying:

```
"warning: The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed."
```

[image]

Now I can see from [this](http://blog.wafrat.com/ignoring-lint-warnings-in-dart/) and [this](https://fartlang.org/guides/language/analysis-options.html), that I can do:

```
// ignore: unused_field
```

But how do I know the error / warning type from the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Suppress` clause in the start of desired file.

Usually I use in all files from all my projets:

```
@file:Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE","NAME_SHADOWING")
```

Unfortunately I did not find the list of clauses accepted.

For some reason, that I don't know, use `File`, `Settings`, `Inpections` and unselect some item or change the severity (typo, warning, weak warning etc) and after Apply, doesn't work.